# CSS3 -moz-transform: rotateY not working as expected

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I try to flip a div with CSS3's transform attribute but it's not rendered properly in Firefox.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zyzu/5/

Leave your mouse over the red square and see the problem.

(While rotating the red square in Firefox, the text on the red square's backface is hidden under the previous square (blue), then as soon as the rotation animation has finished, the text jumps above the blue square).

Code below:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div id="s1" class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"><p>front</p></div>
        <div class="back"><p>back</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="s2" class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"><p>hello</p></div>
        <div class="back"><p>world</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { height:200px; width:200px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }
#s2 .front { background-color:#f00; }
#s2 .back { background-color:#0f0; }
#s1 .front { background-color:#00f; }
#s1 .back { background-color:#0ff; }

.flip-container { perspective: 1000; -webkit-perspective: 1000; -moz-perspective: 1000; }
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front { z-index: 2; }
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, I don't see any issue

Comment: Did you test on Firefox? Yes it flips, but there is a problem with the background color (green) when you hover over the red square. (the red's square backface has a green background color, the green is hidden by the previous square (blue) while rotating, then suddenly appears above it)

Comment: I've update the jsfiddle, added text on the backface. You can see in Firefox that while rotating the red square, the text goes below the previous square (blue), then jumps above it when rotation is finished. In Chrome that problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Not seeing this issue in Firefox 24.

Comment: I have Firefox 24 as well (Win7). And for me the text "Lorem ipsum..." behind the red square goes below the blue square while rotating. Isn't that the case for you??

Comment: No, sorry, not seeing that.

Comment: Works for me as well in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, may be it's an expected behaviour, but you are not ensuring that it happens :-)

Not really an universal answer, but just to show you the way:

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zyzu/6/)

I added

```
#s1 {   -moz-transform: translateZ(1000px);}
```

To send the first div backwards; Now the second div is visible during all the rotation.